# What to do when both dependent and some independent variables are repeated measures?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

Good afternoon

I am working on a study where the dependent variable (% of people in one ethnic group voting, essentially) and one of the independent variables (% of such people in the population) are measured annually for 10 years. There are other independent variables that are not time dependent.

I could run a separate model for each year of the dependent variable, including only the earlier years' data for the independent variable, but was wondering if there was some more parsimonious method.

I have access to R and SAS

(If I've overlooked something obvious, my apologies, I have a bad cold and am not at my best)

Peter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: if you have 10 data points for each IV, what's wrong with regressing all IVs, including the non time-dependent, against the 10 DVs?

Comment: Hi @RobertKubrick Thanks for response. First, do you mean one DV at a time, or all DVs at once? If the latter, how? Second, it wouldn't make sense to have an IV that is later in time than the DV. A DV measured in 1950 can't have an IV measured in 1955.

Comment: Maybe I see what you mean now: you only have 10 data points for one of the IVs, which is also time dependent, so for the very first year for example you would only have 1 IV observation to regress against?

Comment: I think that's it. The DV and one IV are measured at the same ten time points. If I had, e.g. 100 time points I'd look at a multivariate time series. But with only 10?

Comment: I think I may be missing something but it sounds like you just have a usual repeated measures type of situation. Why can't you just do the usual tricks for repeated measures data (random effects or GEE)? As long as you don't have $t$ in the model, the time-varying covariate's effect should be estimable. Another interpretation of this question is that you think the covariate effects themselves are time varying - in that case you could fit each time point separately (or include a categorical interaction with time) and compare the fit of that model to a submodel that does not stratify by time.

Comment: Hi @macro Looking at it some more, I think you're right. My head was kind of stuffed up.

Comment: Why not a hierarchical model, with varying coefficients by year?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the main problem is that you only have 10 observations for the time-dependent IV and you can only use the same or previous year observations in the model, relative to the DV.

If you must use the time-dependent IV (I read you have other IVs?) and the goal is forecasting, one approach is to focus on the last year data and run [simulations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471822906) given the probability distribution function of the rare variable. Of course, you're making lots of assumptions about the behavior of the IV over time, but you can't possibly get something from nothing.

Do you have access to the methodology used to calculate this IV? Can you reconstruct it based on some other data?